# Regex match with multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex that takes out all parts of a string in between citation marks.

> `\(([^)]*)\)`

So

> *- (Hello) + (World) -

returns two matches

> 1. (Hello)
> 2. (World)

Im trying but failing to modify it so that i also get the parts in between as their own matches. Like:

> 1. *-
> 2. (Hello)
> 3. +
> 4. (World)
> 5. -

Is it even possible?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: C# Ill add it to the question

Comment: `Regex.Split(s, @"(\([^)]*\))")`. Or `Regex.Split(s, @"\(([^)]*)\)")` depending on whether you need to keep the parentheses or not.

Comment: Wow! So easy. I didnt know the difference. Care to make it into an answer and i can accept it?

Comment: It is only easy with your regex as it does not contain backreferences with "technical" capturing groups. Then, it will extract too much as you can't convert a capturing group to non-capturing then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, with the current regex, you may use `Regex.Split` with the pattern wrapped in a capturing group:

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(s, @"(\([^)]*\))");
```

Or even, when matches occur in the leading/trailing positions:

```
var tokens = Regex.Split(s, @"(\([^)]*\))").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=*-+%28Hello%29+%2b+%28World%29+-):

[image]

Note you may need to replace all capturing groups in your regex into non-capturing to use this feature. When you use "technical" capturing groups to later refer to using backreferences, you would have to build the non-matching substring array using multiple matching and calling `.Substring()` on the input using the information on the match position.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either the parenthesis with the characters `\([^)]*\)` or `|` match one or more times the characters listed in a character class `[*+-]+`

[`\([^)]*\)|[*+-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/mmwC6O/1)

```
string pattern = @"\([^)]*\)|[*+-]+";
string input = @"*- (Hello) + (World) - ";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

That would give you:

```
*-
(Hello)
+
(World)
-
```

[Demo C#](http://rextester.com/JLFP29645)